# Calculate Mode - "Highest frequency row" DB2

Tags: db2

What would be the most efficient way to calculating the mode across tables with joins in DB2..

I am trying to get the value with the most frequency(count) for a given column(ID - candidate key for joined table) on a given date.

The idea is to get the most common (value) from the table which has different (value)s for some accounts (for the same ID and date). We need to make it unique for use in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use common table expressions [CTE's], indicated by `WITH`, to break the logic down into logical steps. First we'll build the summary rows, then we'll assign a ranking to the rows within each group, then pick out the ones that with the highest count of records.

Let's say we want to know which flavor of each item sells the most frequently on each date (perhaps assuming a record is quantity one).

```
WITH s as
( 
  SELECT itemID, saleDate, flavor, count(*) as tally
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY itemID, saleDate, flavor
), r as
( 
  SELECT itemID, saleDate, flavor, tally, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY itemID, saleDate ORDER BY tally desc) as pri
    FROM s
)
SELECT itemID, saleDate, flavor, tally
  FROM r
  WHERE pri = 1
```

Here the names "s" and "r" refer to the result set from their respective CTE's.  These names can then be used as to represent a table in another part of the statement.

The pri column will have the RANK() of tally value on the summary row from the first section "s" within the window of itemID and saleDate.  Tally is descending, because we want the largest value first, which will get a RANK() of 1.  Then in the main SELECT we simply pick those summary records which were first in their partition.

By using RANK() or DENSE_RANK() we could get back multiple flavors for an itemID, saleDate, if they are tied for first place.  This could be eliminated by replacing RANK() with ROW_NUMBER(), but it would arbitrarily pick one of the tied flavors as a winner, and this may not be correct answer for the problem at hand.

If we had a sales quantity column in the table, we could replace COUNT(*) with SUM(salesqty) and find what had sold the most units.

Comment: hey, Thanks for your reply, That kind of solves the issue..Is there a way to break the tie as well?? If there are two rows at rank 1??

Comment: Well breaking the tie might depend on the specifics of your situation.  If you could describe your scenario, I *might* have some idea.  The scenario I made up for the answer above is kinda lame :o)

Comment: Thanks for the "Rank() Over" concept (and syntax). Glad I found your post.